# how can i convert my rupees into dollars? and what about the tax deduction

Tags: foreign-exchange, money-transfer

I have INR (Indian Rupees) in my bank account and I wish to convert INR to USD and Send it to my friend who is in america. he is in need of 1 lakh and 20 thousand 1600 USD.how much tax i have to pay for this amount.

I am kind of new to these and If yes, please help me out.

Comment: There is no tax on conversions or transfers. Tax is typically on _income_.

Comment: @Aganju could the question be about forex / international bank transfer fees? that would make a lot more sense